# Doctrine Foreign key cascade delete/update exceeds max depth of 15

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am using Symfony:2.8 with doctrine-bundle: 1.5.

my doctrine association mapping is One-To-Many, Self-referencing Bidirectional [One-To-Many, Self-referencing](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing).

here is my code:

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Ranking", mappedBy="parent")
 */
private $children;

/**
 * @var Ranking
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ranking", inversedBy="children")
 *
 * @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")
 */
private $parent;
```

when I am trying to delete row then I am getting this error: **General error: 3008 Foreign key cascade delete/update exceeds max depth of 15."**

My question is there any way that I can increase doctrine's max depth.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.
Actually it's MySQL restriction, not Doctrine.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

> If ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL recurses to update the same
>   table it has previously updated during the cascade, it acts like
>   RESTRICT. This means that you cannot use self-referential ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL operations. This is to prevent infinite
>   loops resulting from cascaded updates. A self-referential ON DELETE
>   SET NULL, on the other hand, is possible, as is a self-referential ON
>   DELETE CASCADE. **Cascading operations may not be nested more than 15
>   levels deep**.